# Is it possible to start a new redmine project with default issues?

Tags: redmine

I have a project that has gone through several iterations (for different clients) and will continue to go through more.  By this point, I know that when I start a new instance of this project, there are certain things that need to be done to get the new project up and running.

Rather than create these issues by hand each time, I'd like to start new instances of this project with default issues.  I've read through the redmine wiki, but don't see an explicit way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you can copy existing issues, and it is even possible to copy multiple issues at once. (in the issues page, select them and right click on one of them)

Maybe the easiest way is to copy the issues from a previous project and assign them to the new project.